# Pandas:Calculate mean of a group of n values of each columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of the following type:

```
     A      B    
0    1      2    
1    4      5    
2    7      8    
3    10    11   
4    13    14   
5    16    17
```

I want to calculate the mean of the first 3 element of each column and then next 3 elements and so on and then store in a dataframe.

Desired Output-

```
      A      B    
0     4      5
1     12    14
```

Using Group By was one of the approach I thought of but I am unable to figure out how to use Group by in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If default `RangeIndex` then use integer division and pass to `groupby`:

```
df = df.groupby(df.index // 3).mean()
print (df)
    A   B
0   4   5
1  13  14
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.index // 3)
Int64Index([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], dtype='int64')
```

General solution with array created by length of DataFrame - working with all index values:

```
df = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 3).mean()
```

**Detail**:

```
print (np.arange(len(df)) // 3)
[0 0 0 1 1 1]
```